# Jmeter: How to control a http sampler request in a thread group to run only once among 100 threads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, beanshell

I've a thread group to run for 100+ users with-in that there is a need to execute a particular http request only once for all the threads. I know the "Once only Controller" but it execute the child samplers once per thread that is why it doesn't meet the requirement here:

As shown in the image: The "once only controller" run the request E & F only once for every thread where as **I my requirement to run the sampler request E & F once only for all the threads A, B, C & D**. having said that if i run the 100+ thread request E & F should run only 1 time.

Is there any way to achieve this in jmeter??

Problem ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: When do you want E & F to run ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I want E & F to be executed once all the http requests gets completed, i.e. if there are 100 threads for 99 thread it should skip the E & F but for 100th thread it should include E & F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your requests `E` and `F` under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and use the following condition:

```
${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && vars.getIteration() == 1)}
```

[image: If Controller Example]

Where:

- [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) - JMeter Function allowing execution of arbitrary [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) code
- `ctx` - shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance
- `vars` - shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, I'll tweak the above code to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct logic controller to achieve this. Usually this type of requirement should be part of `setup` or `tear down` thread group.

If it has to be part of your regular thread group, then it can be achieved by using some workaround.  example:

**Once Only Controller + If Controller:**

If controller will execute E & F only if  `${__threadNum} == 1`. This way we can block other threads from executing E & F